# Is there a way to play local (not embedded) WAV files in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, wav

Without using HTML5 ? I need it in Babylon. Something like  I have tried it and there is no fruit.

Comment: You're using WebGL and yet you don't want to use HTML 5?  That doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can play it with flash.  If you decide to go that route, check out [this article](http://www.phon.ucl.ac.uk/home/mark/audio/play9.htm).

If by "local" you mean "on the user's computer", then that's a whole different ballgame, though.

Comment: <embed hidden="false" autostart="true" src="1.wav" />